# DNS pointing to different IP Address and late propogating

Tags: dns, domain-name

I have run a check using a number of web dns checking tools, eg https://dnschecker.org and it shows in some parts of the world there are A records for my domain but that they point to 2 ip addresses and not 1 and also to completely different ip addresses to the hosting tomcat server I expect them to point to , these wrong ip addresses are 198.105.254.11 and 104.239.213.7.

```
https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.liverpoolitalianopera.co.uk
```

here is what I would expect it to be like (my other domain) given the record in cpanel.

```
https://dnschecker.org/#A/innerfacetesting.net
```

pointing to the tomcat server.

I don't know how to find out what the name servers are if you need that information because enom doesn't tell me that and cpanel advanced dns doesn't tell me that.

I have tomcat hosting with a hosting provider and purchased one domain name through them and mapped it to my tomcat application.  They set up for me for that new domain DNS to point to the tomcat server's IP Address 198.38.82.94.  The jvm is private but the server is shared so the server then maps incoming requests to my applications based on a domain mapping that is setup.  This all works fine.

After this I purchased through them another domain.  They told me that for this one I must set up my own DNS records on my own through

```
http://access.enom.com/
```

I set up two A records one with www and one without, each pointing to 198.38.82.94.  When I logged into enom two name servers clearly owned by the hosting people (from looking at the name) were listed below two radio buttons denoted default and custom.  The custom radio button was selected.  I COULD NOT add any A records without changing the radio button to default.  After I switched to default I added the two A records and saved everything.

A bit later I entered my hosting provider's cpanel advanced dns configuration interface to look at my first domain's DNS settings and discovered that multiple records had been setup automatically for my second domain by the hosting provider all also pointing to 198.38.82.94, just like the two I setup in enom but many more of them.

It is now 3 days and the state of the DNS propogation is still as per at the top of this post.  I have raised a ticket for support with the hosting and domain provider but they say I must put my enquiry on a different ticket which is about a different question but my ticket history list is empty and they will not explain why.

I understand the very basics of DNS but can someone please help me with a better understanding that might help me understand / figure what might be going wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should leave the radio button to `custom` in http://access.enom.com/.

From the google results, mochahost.com had a bad reputation.
Since it's been 3 days, I suggest you to call their service number. If they still can't help, you should consider about transfer your domain name to another service provider.